# How do you find out what Joomla components are being used from frontend?

Tags: web, joomla

Trying to find out what component [this website](http://simplyhealth-calm.com/) is using for its appointment scheduling.

Any way to find that out as a user from the front end? Somewhere in the developer's console perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on **Schedule Appointment** on the top menu, I'm sure you might have seen that it redirects you to `https://www.mindbodyonline.com`.

This is the 3rd party appointment scheduling system but it's not a Joomla component

Answer (score 1):

The scheduling part of the site, is not built in joomla. It uses asp, and Microsoft technologies.

As for the rest of the site doen't seem to be built in something special (it is just articles).